# Azure Artifacts - Downloading Maven package content throws azure UnhandledPromiserejectionWarning

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines, pom.xml, azure-artifacts, azure-pipelines-tasks

One of our development teams have recently migrated their Maven project files from another version control system to Azure DevOps. However, a major caveat is that these Maven projects were created with no POM files (I have no idea why).

The project team have in any case managed to move all of their Maven packages into Azure Artifacts. When a release pipeline job is then run, it is then expected to retrieve the desired artifacts (*.war files) from Azure Artifacts, download to the agent's artifacts directory and subsequently deploy to the target server. The pipeline itself is completed successfully (all tasks set to green status), however when we review the output log, we discover that the artifacts were never downloaded and instead, the download task returns an "UnhandledPromiserejectionWarning". Any idea why this is happening?

So far, we've tried using CURL as an alternative to download the artifacts, but all has been in vain. Naturally, we've also tried and failed with the Azure Artifacts' dedicated "Download Package" pipeline task, but are willing to try an alternative solution, if anyone has some kind suggestions. Been wondering something like Powershell (or other script) can for instance be used to download the desired package files.

I must also mention that the CURL option only appears to fail over a failed OAuth authentication. Any advice on that front will also be helpful, as it is probably our quickest route to a workaround.

Comment: Did you check "*continue on error*" box of that task in your Azure DevOps pipeline? Could you set `system.debug=true` and share related `"UnhandledPromiserejectionWarning"` part log here?

Comment: Hi hitman126, any update on this ticket? Have you figure out it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it turns out the problem was just the capital case.
The DownloadPackage task was trying to download 0.0.30-SNAPSHOT, but instead you can only download the package as 0.0.30-snapshot, as it states on the [microsoft official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-package?view=azure-devops#download-a-maven-package-from-a-project-scoped-feed-and-download-only-pom-files).

In order to fix it, I had to install an [external plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks), then add an additional task before download, that task was converting the name to lower case.

I was using the classical release pipeline, btw.

[image]

Comment: am too facing the same issue. Is there any better solution now?